# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'id' of undefined Stripe Javascript

Tags: javascript, token, stripe-payments

I have been attempting to add stripe into an app I am trying to get an MVP of at the moment. Whenever I type in the test credit card and click send I get sent to a screen with the following error code.

Error Code

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
CheckoutForm._callee$
src/components/CheckoutForm.js:17
  14 |       let response = await fetch("/charge", {
  15 |         method: "POST",
  16 |         headers: {"Content-Type": "text/plain"},
> 17 |         body: token.id
  18 |       });
  19 | 
  20 |       if (response.ok) this.setState({complete: true});
```

Server.js

```
 const app = require("express")();
 const stripe = require("stripe")("STRIPE_SECRET_KEY");
 app.use(require("body-parser").text());
 app.post("/charge", async (req, res) => {
    try {
      let {status} = await stripe.charges.create({
           amount: 2000,
           currency: "usd",
           description: "An example charge",
           source: req.body
         });

           res.json({status});
         } catch (err) {
           res.status(500).end();
         }
       });
       app.listen(9000, () => console.log("Listening on port 9000"));
```

CheckoutForm.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {CardElement, injectStripe} from 'react-stripe-elements';


class CheckoutForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = {complete: false};
     this.submit = this.submit.bind(this);
  }

  async submit(ev) {
    let {token} = await this.props.stripe.createToken({name: "Name"});
    let response = await fetch("/charge", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {"Content-Type": "text/plain"},
      body: token.id
    });

    if (response.ok) this.setState({complete: true});
  }

render() {
   if (this.state.complete) return <h1>Purchase Complete</h1>;

return (
  <div className="checkout">
     <p>Would you like to complete the purchase?</p>
     <CardElement />
     <button onClick={this.submit}>Send</button>
 </div>
   );
 }
}

export default injectStripe(CheckoutForm);
```

App.js

```
import {Elements, StripeProvider} from 'react-stripe-elements';
import CheckoutForm from './components/CheckoutForm';

  <StripeProvider apiKey="STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY">
    <div className="example">
      <h1>React Stripe Elements Example</h1>
      <Elements>
        <CheckoutForm />
      </Elements>
    </div>
  </StripeProvider>
```

I am not the best and haven't been able to find anything to help me so far.
Please and Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

createToken can return an error, but it doesn't reject the promise(some discussion [here](https://github.com/stripe/react-stripe-elements/issues/175#issuecomment-371949735)), instead the returned token will be null. It's necessary to handle the error like this :

```
this.props.stripe.createToken({name : 'Name').then(({token, error}) => {
  if (error) {
    // handle error
  } else {
    // handle token
  }
});
```

If you do this, you should see what the underlying error is.

Comment: It is having a POST http://localhost:3001/charge 404 (Not Found) error, I have tried looking this up and nothing, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

From you code it seems that `this.props.stripe.createToken` does not return an object with property `token` as you are destructuring the response. Its value is `undefine` right now. 
Your response for `this.props.stripe.createToken` should be like this to work this code ;

`let response = await this.props.stripe.createToken({name: "Name"});`

```
 response = {
  token: {
   id: 'some id'
  },
  //other properties.
 }
```

You may need to check `createToken` function why its not returning right response.

Answer (score 0):

Display the error using :

```
this.props.stripe.createToken({name : 'Name'}).then(({token, error}) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    // handle token
  }
});
```

Also, in my case, I was putting an australian post code (only 4 digits), where stripe is actually expecting a different format,
In order to avoid this, I used this property :

```
 <CardElement hidePostalCode={true} />
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

**localhost:3001/charge** is not found because there is indeed no such thing. Instead you should modify the code to send request to backend. For example:

```
let response = await fetch("http://localhost:8081/charge", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {"Content-Type": "text/plain"},
      body: token.id
    });
```

After that you should see the underlying error.